# Update bootstrap to version 3 Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap upgrade service for upgrading from Bootstrap 2.x to 3.x

http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/

But I have a problem converting the razor syntax. For example I have:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 form-actions">
        <p>
        <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("ChooseAddItem", "Home")">Action</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And service returns:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-actions">
            <p>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("
                chooseadditem="ChooseAddItem" home="Home">Action</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Look what happens to Url.Action function. This is only small example. I have a lot of files and a lot of code.

Is there any other way of converting razor views to bootstrap 3.x?

Comment: unchecking the "modify nav and modal structure" checkbox prevents that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/

The problem you're seeing is because the service uses jQuery to manipulate the DOM and structure of your HTML. A headless browser is being used, and this changes the actual HTML content upon conversion.

I've added a new switch ("Modify nav and modal structure") to prevent this from happening, but as a result the structure of any  modals and navs will not be converted to Bootstrap 3.

So, if you want to keep the Razor content the same, just uncheck the "Modify nav and modal structure" checkbox before you "Convert to Bootstrap 3" and it should work for you.